# What is the difference between "if" statements with "then" at the end?

Tags: ruby

What's the difference between these two Ruby `if` statements when we put a `then` at the end of the `if` statement?

```
if(val == "hi") then
  something.meth("hello")
else
  something.meth("right")
end
```

and

```
if(val == "hi")
  something.meth("hello")
else
  something.meth("right")
end
```

Answer (score 78, accepted):

`then` is a delimiter to help Ruby identify the condition and the true-part of the expression.

`if` condition `then` true-part `else` false-part `end`

`then` is optional **unless** you want to write an `if` expression in one line. For an if-else-end spanning multiple lines the newline acts as a delimiter to split the conditional from the true-part

```
# can't use newline as delimiter, need keywords
puts if (val == 1) then '1' else 'Not 1' end

# can use newline as delimiter
puts if (val == 1)
  '1'
else
  'Not 1'
end
```

Comment: In Ruby, `if` is an expression, not a statement. In fact, *everything* is an expression, there are no statements. Thus, both your examples would be better written like `puts if val == 1 then '1' else 'Not 1' end`.

Comment: @Jorg - right. It'll take some time to scrub the years of C off me. :)

Comment: In ruby 2.1.2, `puts if (1 == 1) then '1' else 'not 1' end` raises an `syntax error, unexpected keyword_then, expecting end-of-input` unless you put the if statement in parentheses `puts (if (1 == 1) then '1' else 'not 1' end)`.

Comment: For completeness, you should favour the [ternary operator](https://github.com/bbatsov/ruby-style-guide#ternary-operator) for single line if expressions. `puts(1==1 ? '1' : 'Not 1')`

Answer (score 13):

Here's a quick tip that is not directly related to your question: in Ruby, there is no such thing as an `if` statement. In fact, in Ruby, there are no statements *at all*. *Everything* is an expression. An `if` expression returns the value of the last expression that was evaluated in the branch that was taken.

So, there is no need to write

```
if condition
  foo(something)
else
  foo(something_else)
end
```

This would better be written as

```
foo(
  if condition
    something
  else
    something_else
  end
)
```

Or as a one-liner

```
foo(if condition then something else something_else end)
```

In your example:

```
something.meth(if val == 'hi' then 'hello' else 'right' end)
```

Note: Ruby also has a ternary operator (`condition ? then_branch : else_branch`) but that is completely unnecessary and should be avoided. The only reason why the ternary operator is needed in languages like C is because in C `if` is a statement and thus cannot return a value. You need the ternary operator, because it is an expression and is the only way to return a value from a conditional. But in Ruby, `if` is already an expression, so there is really no need for a ternary operator.

Comment: In Ruby there are many ways to reach the same goal. I personally like the ternary operator. I find it compact and readable :)

Comment: We use ruby extensively in our build system, I've found that the first syntax is easier to understand for developers coming from other languages.

Comment: Readability is paramount to quality code. Nesting a multi-line branching construct (statement or expression, regardless) inside a parameter list is absurd. It requires to much scanning and consideration to even get a high-level idea of what is going on. 

Spend a few extra keystrokes and lose a whisp of DRY to make your code more readable and supportable. 

Sneaking in a (simple) ternary operator does not violate that readability and would not get rejected in a pull request.

Answer (score 8):

The `then` is only required if you want to write the `if` expression on one line:

```
if val == "hi" then something.meth("hello")
else something.meth("right")
end
```

That brackets in your example are not significant, you can skip them in either case.

See the [Pickaxe Book](http://ruby-doc.org/docs/ProgrammingRuby/html/tut_expressions.html#UH) for details.

Answer (score 7):

The only time that I like to use `then` on a multi-line `if/else` (yes, I know it's not required) is when there are multiple conditions for the `if`, like so:

```
if some_thing? ||
  (some_other_thing? && this_thing_too?) ||
  or_even_this_thing_right_here?
then
  some_record.do_something_awesome!
end
```

I find it to be much more readable than either of these (completely valid) options:

```
if some_thing? || (some_other_thing? && this_thing_too?) || or_even_this_thing_right_here?
  some_record.do_something_awesome!
end

# or

if some_thing? ||
  (some_other_thing? && this_thing_too?) ||
  or_even_this_thing_right_here?
  some_record.do_something_awesome!
end
```

Because it provides a visual delineation between the condition(s) of the `if` and the block to execute if the condition(s) are "truthy".

Answer (score 4):

There's no difference at all.

And, just FYI, your code can be optimized to

```
something.meth( val == 'hi' ? 'hello' : 'right' )
```

Comment: Shortened, instead of "optimized"?

Comment: Shorter but less clear. I never use that structure outside rapid prototypes.

Comment: Nice use of a ternary operator!