# File.exist? always returns false even when file does exist

Tags: ruby, file

I have a program that tries to open a file:

```
Dir.chdir(File.dirname(__FILE__))
puts "Enter file name: ";
relPath = gets;
absPath = Dir.pwd << "/" << relPath;
if File.exist?(absPath) then
    puts "File exists";
    file = File.open(absPath, "r");
    other code...
else
    puts "File does not exist";
end
```

It always prints "File does not exist" even when the current directory exists and the file also exists. The file and script are in the same directory.

I am running it on Mac OS X Yosemite (10.10.3) and Ruby 2.2.0p0.

Comment: `if` *can* have a `then`. `;` isn't idiomatic but Ruby allows it. It's not well written but that's different.

Comment: I'm new to ruby, I usually work with Java and JavaScript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't explain why (albeit I have strong belief that it's for some whitespace characters) but with this little contribution it works ok.

```
Dir.chdir(File.dirname(__FILE__))
print "Enter file name:";
relPath = gets.chomp; #intuitively used this, and it wroked fine
absPath = File.expand_path(relPath) #used builtin function expand_path instead of string concatenation
puts absPath
puts File.file?(absPath)
if File.exist?(absPath) then

    puts "File exists";
    puts File.ctime(absPath) #attempting a dummy operation :)

else
    puts "File does not exist";
end
```

runnning code

```
$ ls -a anal*
analyzer.rb
$ ruby -v
ruby 2.2.0p0 (2014-12-25 revision 49005) [x86_64-linux]
ziya@ziya:~/Desktop/code/ruby$ ruby fileexists.rb 
Enter file name:analyzer.rb
/home/ziya/Desktop/code/ruby/analyzer.rb #as a result of puts absPath
true #File.file?(absPath) => true
File exists
2015-06-11 12:48:31 +0500
```

Comment: the `gets` returns the `"\n"` (newline) character as part of the string. So, using `chomp` removed that extra character. I would also consider using `File.join` if the folder isn't relative to the `Dir.pwd`.

Comment: btw,  `File.join` is more explicit than `File.expand_path`. the latter does its own magic but the first takes at least two arguments which describes the process very clearly. and i should have used it.

Answer (score 0):

That code has syntax error ("if" doesnt need "then"), and you dont have to put ";" after each line.

try

```
Dir.chdir(File.dirname(__FILE__))
puts "Enter file name: "
relPath = gets
absPath = "#{Dir.pwd}/#{relPath.chop}"
if File.exist?(absPath)
  puts "File exists"
  file = File.open(absPath, "r")
else
  puts "File does not exist"
end
```

remember that gets will add a new line character so you will need to do a chomp, and that way to concatenate string won't work on ruby.

Comment: You could consider using `File.join Dir.pwd, relPath.chop` (or `File.expand_path(relPath.chomp)` ) to make it compatible on Windows as well as Unix.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is not idiomatic Ruby. I'd write it something like this untested code:

```
Dir.chdir(File.dirname(__FILE__))

puts 'Enter file name: '
rel_path = gets.chomp
abs_path = File.absolute_path(rel_path)

if File.exist?(abs_path)

  puts 'File exists'
  File.foreach(abs_path) do |line|
    # process the line
  end

else
  puts 'File does not exist'
end
```

While Ruby supports the use of `;`, they're for use when we absolutely must provide multiple commands on one line. The *ONLY* time I can think of needing that is when using Ruby to execute single-line commands at the command-line. In normal scripts I've never needed `;` between statements.

`then` is used with `if` when we're using a single line `if` expression, however, we have trailing `if` which removes the need for `then`. For instance, these accomplish the same thing but the second is idiomatic, shorter, less verbose and easier to read:

```
if true then a = 1 end
a = 1 if true
```

See "[What is the difference between "if" statements with "then" at the end?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3083636/128421)" for more information.

Instead of `relPath` and `absPath` we use snake_case for variables, so use `rel_path` and `abs_path`. It_is_a_readability AndMaintenanceThing.

[`File.absolute_path(rel_path)`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/File.html#method-c-absolute_path) is a good way to take the starting directory and return the absolute path given a relative directory.

[`File.foreach`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/IO.html#method-c-foreach) is a very fast way to read a file, faster than slurping it using something like `File.read`. It is also scalable whereas `File.read` is not.

Comment: You didn't address the question that OP asked...